# Why don't I have access to certain parts of a package?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am trying to implement the OAuth2 Client Credentials flow with Spring's WebClient like it's described by Baeldung (see here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-oauth2).

When I write this line of code

```
ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
  new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
    clientRegistrations,
    new UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository());
```

IntelliJ says that it doesn't know "ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction".
The documentation of spring says that the package to import is as follows (see here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/reactive/function/client/ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.html):

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client
```

I have the following dependencies concerning Spring Security OAuth2:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

When I try to manually import it, I come until here:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client
```

IntelliJ suggests me a few options, but I need .web which is not listed.
[Here is an image of IntelliJs suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHxN7.png)

And then no suggestions for ".web.reactive.function.client".
Why doesn't this work?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you see `spring-security-oauth2-client` in the list of External Libraries in IntelliJ? Basically are you sure that maven picked up the dependency. If it's listed in the dependencies, may be try restarting IntelliJ and invalidating the cache.

Comment: `<type>pom</type>` <- Why are you using the POM dependency type? If you want to add the oauth2 client as a dependency and not just its pom, then just using the default dependency type should be the correct approach.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, guys. Meanwhile I've removed the POM type, invalidated caches and restarted the IDE. But the result is still the same. The dependency is now listed in the list of external libraries, but it still doesn't work....
I've added an image in the post - if you want to take a look at it...